# Swift, value not updated

Tags: swift, swiftui

in the file Maze.swift, I have:

```
var myMaze = Maze() // -> 9.0
```

the Maze struct definition with the following content:

```
@State var widthDouble = 9.0
```

and the init() method

```
init() {
print("Maze init:", self.widthDouble) }
```

In the file ContentView.swift, I have the following:

```
@State var widthDouble = myMaze.widthDouble
Slider(value: $widthDouble, in: 3...33, step: 1) // updated to 16.0
Button(action: { action() }) { Text("Build maze with updated values") }
```

and finally the func action()

```
func action() {
myMaze.widthDouble = widthDouble
print("ContentView: ", widthDouble) // -> 16.0
print("ContentView (myMaze.): ", myMaze.widthDouble) // -> 9.0
myMaze = .init() }
```

Although in func action() myMaze.widthDouble is assigned with widthDouble (16.0), the value of myMaze.widthDouble is not updated and is still 9.0 !

Output of init():
Maze init: 9.0

Value 9.0 updated to 16.0 in slider

Output of action():
ContentView:  16.0
ContentView (myMaze.):  9.0

Output of init():
Maze init: 9.0

Can somebody tell me what is wrong and why the myMaze.widthDouble is not updated?

File ContentView.swift

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Maze
//
//  Created by Philippe Lagarrigue on 24/12/2020.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    
    let numTabs = 2
    let minDragTranslationForSwipe: CGFloat = 50
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab){
            NavigationView{
                MenuView()
                .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image("map")
                Text("Map")
            }.tag(0)
             .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture().onEnded({
                 self.handleSwipe(translation: $0.translation.width)
             }))
            NavigationView{
                MenuView()
                .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image("navigation")
                Text("Navigation")
            }.tag(1)
             .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture().onEnded({
                 self.handleSwipe(translation: $0.translation.width)
             }))
        }
    }
    
    private func handleSwipe(translation: CGFloat) {
        if translation > minDragTranslationForSwipe && selectedTab > 0 {
            selectedTab -= 1
        } else  if translation < -minDragTranslationForSwipe && selectedTab < numTabs-1 {
            selectedTab += 1
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct MenuView : View {
    @State var widthDouble = myMaze.widthDouble
    @State var heightDouble = myMaze.heightDouble
    @State var oneWay = myMaze.oneWay
    @State private var isEditing1 = false
    @State private var isEditing2 = false
    //@Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    var body : some View {
        HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.top) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Number of rooms (horizontally): \(widthDouble, specifier: "%.0f")")
                    .foregroundColor(isEditing1 ? .red : .black)
                Slider(value: $widthDouble, in: 3...33, step: 1,
                       onEditingChanged: { editing in isEditing1 = editing })
                Divider()
                // format: "Angle: %.0f", angle
                Text("Number of rooms (vertically): \(heightDouble, specifier: "%.0f")")
                    .foregroundColor(isEditing2 ? .red : .black)
                Slider(value: $heightDouble, in: 3...33, step: 1,
                       onEditingChanged: { editing in isEditing2 = editing })
                Divider()
                Toggle("One way", isOn: $oneWay)
                Button(action: { action() }) { Text("Build maze with updated values") }
            } .padding()
        }
    }
    func action() {
        myMaze.widthDouble = widthDouble
        myMaze.heightDouble = heightDouble
        print("ContentView: ", widthDouble, heightDouble)
        print("ContentView (myMaze.): ", myMaze.widthDouble, myMaze.heightDouble)
        myMaze = .init()
    }
}
```

File Maze.swift

```
//
//  Maze.swift
//  NewMaze
//
//  Created by Philippe Lagarrigue on 23/12/2020.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

let wall = (North: 1, East: 2, South: 4, West: 8) // 15 means all walls
let exit = (toNorth: 16, toEast: 32, toSouth: 64, toWest: 128) // 0 means no exit
var myMaze = Maze()

struct Room {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
    var roomsToExit: Int
}

struct Maze {
    // Properties
    var width = 9
    var height = 12
    var widthDouble = 9.0
    var heightDouble = 12.0
    var oneWay = true
    var exitRoom = Room(x: 0, y: 0, roomsToExit: 0)
    var farestRoom = Room(x: 0, y: 0, roomsToExit: 0)
    var mazeData = [[Int]]()
    var numberOfRooms: Int { return self.width * self.height }
    
    // Methods
    init() {
        //print(self.widthDouble, self.heightDouble)
        self.width = Int(self.widthDouble)
        self.height = Int(self.heightDouble)
        mazeData = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 15, count: height), count: width)
        print("Maze init:", self.width, "x", self.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: @State are only to be used in views for properties updated in a UI component so you should not have it in a model(?) type like Maze. Other than that I must say it is very hard to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Thx for the answer but could you tell me how I can update my value <myMaze.widthDouble> outside of the struct?

Comment: @Swiftiti remove `@State` from  `var widthDouble = 9.0` in your `struct Maze ` and it will work (Tested)

Comment: I just removed State and could compile without error but the value <myMaze.widthDouble> is still not updated!

Comment: It's a little strange that you call init() on your maze variable after you have updated the property. To me it looks like you need two types, one maze model and one maze builder, say `Maze` and `MazeBuilder`. I would sugget looking into `ObservableObject` and `@Published` and use that for your builder class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `@State` is used for changes inside within view
- `@ObservedObject` is used to store `ObservableObject`.
- `@Published` publishes when `@Published var` changes itself.

with this knowledge, here is the answer.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    
    let numTabs = 2
    let minDragTranslationForSwipe: CGFloat = 50
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab){
            NavigationView{
                MenuView()
                .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image("map")
                Text("Map")
            }.tag(0)
             .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture().onEnded({
                 self.handleSwipe(translation: $0.translation.width)
             }))
            NavigationView{
                MenuView()
                .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image("navigation")
                Text("Navigation")
            }.tag(1)
             .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture().onEnded({
                 self.handleSwipe(translation: $0.translation.width)
             }))
        }
    }
    
    private func handleSwipe(translation: CGFloat) {
        if translation > minDragTranslationForSwipe && selectedTab > 0 {
            selectedTab -= 1
        } else  if translation < -minDragTranslationForSwipe && selectedTab < numTabs-1 {
            selectedTab += 1
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct MenuView : View {
    @ObservedObject var myMaze = Maze()
    @State private var isEditing1 = false
    @State private var isEditing2 = false
    //@Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    var body : some View {
        HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.top) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Number of rooms (horizontally): \(myMaze.widthDouble, specifier: "%.0f")")
                    .foregroundColor(isEditing1 ? .red : .black)
                Slider(value: $myMaze.widthDouble, in: 3...33, step: 1,
                       onEditingChanged: { editing in isEditing1 = editing })
                Divider()
                // format: "Angle: %.0f", angle
                Text("Number of rooms (vertically): \(myMaze.heightDouble, specifier: "%.0f")")
                    .foregroundColor(isEditing2 ? .red : .black)
                Slider(value: $myMaze.heightDouble, in: 3...33, step: 1,
                       onEditingChanged: { editing in isEditing2 = editing })
                Divider()
                Toggle("One way", isOn: $myMaze.oneWay)
                Button(action: { action() }) { Text("Build maze with updated values") }
            } .padding()
        }
    }
    func action() {
        
    }
}

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

let wall = (North: 1, East: 2, South: 4, West: 8) // 15 means all walls
let exit = (toNorth: 16, toEast: 32, toSouth: 64, toWest: 128) // 0 means no exit


struct Room {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
    var roomsToExit: Int
}

class Maze: ObservableObject {
 
    @Published var height = 12
    
    
    @Published var widthDouble = 9.0 {
        didSet {
            setMezData(height: Int(heightDouble), width: Int(widthDouble))
        }
    }
    @Published var heightDouble = 12.0 {
        didSet {
            setMezData(height: Int(heightDouble), width: Int(widthDouble))
        }
    }
    
    @Published var oneWay = true
    @Published var exitRoom = Room(x: 0, y: 0, roomsToExit: 0)
    @Published var farestRoom = Room(x: 0, y: 0, roomsToExit: 0)
    @Published var mazeData = [[Int]]() {
        didSet {
            print(mazeData)
        }
    }
    var numberOfRooms: Int { return Int(heightDouble) * Int(widthDouble) }
    
    func setMezData(height: Int, width: Int) {
        mazeData = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 15, count: height), count: width)
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Thx, I updated everything as proposed and got no error but the mazeData array is not updated with the new values, could you tell me how I could update it? Having < myMaze = .init() > into func action() gives me the following error: Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you, everything works now as expected and I learned a lot!

Comment: Where can I find this tick Mark?

Comment: @Swiftiti https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

with your help I finally found the way how to access a class from other classes.

```
// MyClass definition
class MyClass: ObservableObject {
    static let sharedInstance = MyClass()
    var myProperty = "Something"
    ...
}

// A struct where I need to use MyClass
struct MyView1 : View {
    @ObservedObject var ClassInst = MyClass.sharedInstance
    ...
    ClassInst.myProperty = "Something else"
}

// Another struct where I need to use MyClass
struct MyView2 : View {
    @ObservedObject var ClassInst = MyClass.sharedInstance
    ...
    ClassInst.myProperty = "Nothing"
}
```